# How to deploy angular2-quickstart app to IIS

Tags: angular, deployment, iis-8

I'm trying to deploy **`angular2-quickstart`** app in **`local IIS`** for the first time and new to production ready build process.

***my quick-start app is running fine.***

I've added **gulp** to my project and what I'm doing with gulp is,

[image]

**1)** Creating **dist** folder in **root directory**. **`dist`** Folder

**2)** converting all **`.ts`** into **`.js`** and putting them under **`dist/app`**

**3)** creating **`dist/libs`** which contains **`reflect.js`**,**`shim.min.js`**,**`system.src.js`**,**`zone.js`** as shown in image.

**4)** **`systemjs.config.js`** is as follow (p**lease note**: ***I've made no changes to existing file yet***),

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

**5)** **`index.html`** is as follow,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">



     <!-- changed this section with libs -->


      <script src='lib/shim.min.js'></script>
      <script src='lib/zone.js'></script>
      <script src='lib/Reflect.js'></script>
      <script src='lib/system.src.js'></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/hammerjs/2.0.8/hammer.min.js"></script>
      <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>

      <script>
         System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
      </script>



  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

**6)** I copy **`dist folder's`** content to **`c:/inetpub/wwwroot`** and try to access **`localhost`** in the **`chrome browser`** and I see following in browser's console.

[image]

**7)** I know its incomplete process but I want to complete it and don't know what other things are required.

---

***Now questions are***,

**1)** Do I need to change anything in **systemjs.config.js**? If yes, what?

**2)** As you can see **`systemjs.config.js`** uses **`node_modules`**, what to do for **`angular2 dependencies`**?

**3)** What about other dependencies like **`jquery`**, **`hummerjs`** and etc?

**4)** As I'm not going to have **`node_modules`** folder in **`dist`** folder, what about **node_modules** folder?

**5)** which other files require in **`dist folders`**?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to copy **node_modules folder** to **`c:/inetpub/wwwroot/`** and boom. Now its works as expected.

So finally my **`c:/inetput/wwwroot`** folder contains below folder to run angular2 app successfully,

**app

|_______app.component.js

|_______app.module.js

|_______main.js


lib

|_______Reflect.js

|_______shim.min.js

|_______system.src.js

|_______zone.js


node_modules(*`just copy paste`*)

index.html(*`changed script's path, refer above index.html`*)

systemjs.config.js(`no change`)**

Answer (score -1):

It will be better if we use task runner to do such thing for us,
I'm looking for gulp config and npm script to publish app quickly.

So Angular2 QuickStart should have npm script, e.g **npm run deploy**, for beginner.